# *InterfaceError * psycopg2.InterfaceError: cursor already closed. I want to query data from postgresql database & display some or all of it on my web

Tags: postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to flask world and wondering what causes the program to fail. every time i run my app i'm getting **interfaceError**. i was able to print the data on command line but this error displayed when i'm trying to render on html. thank you so much for your help
here is my mainApp.py file
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from models import People, db
from flask_migrate import Migrate
import psycopg2

```
 # creates an application that is named after the name of the file
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql://student_user:1234@localhost:5432/studentdb"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db.init_app(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
#conn = "postgresql://student_user:1234@localhost:5432/studentdb"
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="teacherdb", host="localhost", user="teacher_user", password=1234)
cur = conn.cursor()
@app.route('/')
def index():
   # Execute a query
   cur.execute("SELECT * FROM teachertb")
   # Retrieve query results
   records = cur.fetchall()
   print(records)
   conn.close()
   return render_template("index.html", records=records)
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>
<body>
    {% for record in range(0, len(records)) %}
        <p>{{ records[record][1] }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lastly, if **name** == "**main**": checks that the current file is being run as the main program and calls app.run(debug=True) to start the application with the debug mode enabled.

Please note that the configuration of the database(like user name,password,host) may have to be updated accordingly. It also seems like the connection is closed before sending the records variable to the template, which may cause the program to not work properly.